# Having a break within a loop and waiting for the person to continue

Tags: python-3.x, psychopy

Hi  i am running an experiment which has 120 trials. i want to add a  break in the loop every  30 trials and wait for the participants to press a key when they are ready to continue.  my code for the loop looks like this

```
start.draw()
win.flip()
event.waitKeys(keyList=['return'])

win.flip()

cross.draw()
win.flip()
event.waitKeys(keyList=['5'])


for stim in stroop:
    colour.text = stim[0]
    colour.color = stim[1]
    colour.draw()
    display_time = win.flip()
```

how can i add a break into this for loop?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enumerate to keep track of the number of iterations made:

```
for idx, stim in enumerate(stroop):
    # The +1 makes it so we avoid asking the user's input on first iteration.
    if (idx + 1) % 30 == 0:
        event.waitKeys(keyList=['return'])
    [...]
```

By the way, `breaks` in python refers to breaking out of the loop. What you want to do is rather "wait for user input".

Comment: Thank you for the info. I cant seem out it in the correct place. does it go under the colour.draw or win.flip or somewhere else?

Comment: The first line replaces your current `for stim in stroop:`. Where you put the rest depends on when you want the pause to occur: before or after the stimuli are drawn?

Comment: Thank you, it is working now!! i want to add  a  screen that say 'Press ENTER to continue' which i have made like this ```continue1= visual.TextStim(win, text = 'Press ENTER to continue', pos = (0,0), color=(1,1,1))``` to add this to the loop would ```continue1.draw()``` go before the ```event.waitKeys()```